# Text lines are not aligned when using lstlisting

Tags: xetex, listings

I want to make a textbox where every line starts on the same column. However, when I compile the document, the lines are not aligned for some reason. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Example}
\lstset{basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, breaklines=true}
\lstset{framextopmargin=10pt,framexbottommargin=10pt,frame=single}
\date{2012\\Julio}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent \textbf{\large{Example 1}}
\bigskip
\begin{lstlisting}
Example text. As you can see here, for some reason, and even though the first line of text is fine, the rest of the lines are not aligned
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Here's what I get when compiling:

[image]

I'm compiling with xetex, I don't know if that matters

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: The "extra" space at the beginning of the last line appears to be the result of an input space not fitting on the broken line.  You might want to test the answer explicitly for that situation.  (I don't have the ability to test, so not tested.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `listings` breaks a line that is too long, it inserts some space at the beginning of the new line(s). You can remove this space by setting `breakindent=0pt` in `\lstset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Example}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    framextopmargin=10pt,
    framexbottommargin=10pt,
    frame=single,
    breakindent=0pt      % <-- NEW
}
\date{2012\\Julio}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent \textbf{\large{Example 1}}
\bigskip
\begin{lstlisting}
Example text. As you can see here, for some reason, and even though the first line of text is fine, the rest of the lines are not aligned
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]